# Pandas: script to calculate linear-model coefficient runs fine on Linux, but not on Windows 10

Tags: python, pandas

The following script runs fine on Linux (Mint 18.1).

The function makes an array "Y" of the monthly sales, and removes the nan values from the array. It then makes a numpy.arange array "X", which goes from 1 up to the length of Y. 
It then makes a linear model based on X and Y, and calculates the coefficient.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from io import StringIO
from sklearn import linear_model as lm

data=
'''Fruit  jan  feb  mar  apr  may  jun  jul  aug  sep  oct  nov  dec
Apples    nan  nan  nan  600  550  620  nan  nan  300  100  200  50
Bananas   740  720  780  700  250  140  20   nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
Kiwis     nan  nan  nan  nan  400  550  nan  500  nan  40   50   nan
Oranges   nan  300  350  300  400  500  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
Grapes    150  200  250  200  50   50   40   35   30   20   10   nan'''

def coefficient(row):
    y   =   np.array(row['jan':'dec'].astype(float))
    y   =   np.nan_to_num(y)
    y   =   y[y != 0]
    x   =   np.arange(1,len(y)+1).reshape(len(y),1)
    return lm.LinearRegression().fit(x,y).coef_

df          =   pd.read_csv(StringIO(data),delimiter='\s+')
df['COEF']  =   df.apply(coefficient,axis=1)
```

This exact same script causes the following error on Windows 10.

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 109, in __init__
len(self.mgr_locs)))

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 13, placement implies 1
```

I am using fully upgraded Anaconda 3 in both cases. Does anyone know why this happens, and how to alter the script to avoid the error on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From some test I've made, the `.coef_` returns an numpy array, which causes some truble. Changing the following line works, I'm just not sure the result is what you want.

```
return lm.LinearRegression().fit(x,y).coef_[0]
```

Comment: Nice workaround, didn't think of that. Still don't see what the OS has to do with it though.

Comment: I don't have a proper linux machine or virtual machine to test. But I can't think of a reason that linux will cause the problem. Maybe you can check the pandas and sklearn versions?

Comment: I've done "conda update --all" on both, but I'll check again when I'm home. Either way _.coef_[0] gives the right result.